# JWT - canActivate:[AuthGuard] not allowing login

Tags: angular, authentication, mean-stack, angular2-jwt

I am creating a sample MEAN authentication app, in which i have a home page, register page, login page, dashboard and profile page. I am trying to apply authentication with the help of angular2-jwt. But it is not working for me. I am stuck at login page. When I enter the username password (correct), the flash message of "You are logged in" appears but does not redirect me to the dashboard page (which was working before authentication part). And when I manually type url of dashboard page (which should be accessible now as I am logged in), it still redirects me to the login page.

Another problem is that I have written code for Login and register buttons to disappear once user log in but they are not disappearing as well after the flash message "you are logged in".

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Here's my navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MEAN Auth App</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile</a></li>

        <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()"><a (click)="onLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

My navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private router:Router,
    private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLogoutClick(){
    this.authService.logout();
    this.flashMessage.show('You are logged out', {
      cssClass:'alert-success',
      timeout: 3000
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';

import {ValidateService} from './services/validate.service';
import {AuthService} from './services/auth.service';
import {FlashMessagesModule} from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import {AuthGuard} from './guards/auth.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes =  [
  {path:'', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  {path:'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FlashMessagesModule
  ],
  providers: [ValidateService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my auth.gaurd.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{
  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router){

  }

  canActivate(){
    if(this.authService.loggedIn()){
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

my auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;
  isDev:boolean;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.isDev = false; // Change to false before deployment
  }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    let ep = this.prepEndpoint('users/register');
    return this.http.post(ep, user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    let ep = this.prepEndpoint('users/authenticate');
    return this.http.post(ep, user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    let ep = this.prepEndpoint('users/profile');
    return this.http.get(ep,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  loggedIn(){
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  prepEndpoint(ep){
    if(this.isDev){
      return ep;
    } else {
      return 'http://localhost:8080/'+ep;
    }
  }
}
```

and my login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  username: String;
  password: String;

  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private router:Router,
    private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoginSubmit(){
    const user = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success){
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
        this.flashMessage.show('You are now logged in', {
          cssClass: 'alert-success',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        console.log("I have navigated");
      } else {
        this.flashMessage.show(data.msg, {
          cssClass: 'alert-danger',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

please let me know if any other file I need to upload. And the "I have navigated" is being printed in console, which is written in login.comonent.ts (I wrote it just to check).

Comment: Use '/' in front of the router navigation like this  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

Comment: still no success. same problem continuing. still not taking me to dashboard.

Comment: Can you check the url after clicking login button if it's changing or not ?

Comment: url is not changing. it remains "localhost:4200/login" even when I press the login button, however the message "you are logged in" is displaying.

Comment: post the code for tokenNotExpired() function ?

Comment: its not written. its imported from angular2-jwt (auth.service.ts 4th line) and called inside loggedIn function in auth.service.ts (55th line).

Comment: @Vignesh : do you reckon that the tokenNotExpired should be written explicitly?